# How to update temp table from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `[DETAIL]` table with columns DetailID, PackageID, TemplateID and DocumentID. The `DetailID` column is the primary key.

Then in the stored procedure, I use a temp table

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    DetailID INT NULL,
    PackageID INT,
    TemplateID INT NULL,
    DocumentID INT NULL,        
)
```

The temp table is already populated with PackageID, TemplateID and DocumentID.
I am trying to update Temp table's DetailID with matching rows. For non matching rows DetailID will be null in temp table

```
UPDATE @temp 
SET DetailID = D.DetailID
FROM Details D
WHERE D.PackageID = @temp.PackageID AND 
                  ((D.TemplateID IS NOT NULL AND D.TemplateID = @temp.TemplateID) OR
                  (D.DocumentID IS NOT NULL AND D.DocumentID = @temp.DocumentID))
```

I am getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@temp"

Comment: FWIW, the null checks are superfluous. A null will never equal a null, so checking that `templateid is not null` and then also checking an equality on it does an unnecessary check. SQL may optimize them away, but it may not. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I dont want to select rows if both templateid and documentid are null

Comment: Right. Same applies to document id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one solution to the problem ([demo](http://rextester.com/KIRLI59547))

Alternatively you can use the `UPDATE ... FROM .... JOIN` syntax and give it an alias.

```
UPDATE @temp
SET DetailID = D.DetailID
FROM Details D
WHERE D.PackageID = [@temp].PackageID AND 
                  ((D.TemplateID IS NOT NULL AND D.TemplateID = [@temp].TemplateID) OR
                  (D.DocumentID IS NOT NULL AND D.DocumentID = [@temp].DocumentID))
```

Comment: ahh.. so i was missing [...]

Comment: @LP13 Yes, but the first instance does **not** require those, I made that mistake then edited it.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to this:

```
UPDATE t 
SET DetailID = D.DetailID
FROM Details D
JOIN @temp t
    ON t.PackageID = d.PackageID
    AND (
        (D.TemplateID IS NOT NULL AND D.TamplateID = t.TemplateID) 
        OR (D.DocumentID IS NOT NULL AND D.DocumentID = t.DocumentID)
    )
```